# Power flickering on one of five receptacles

Tags: electrical, wiring

I finished the basement for my son, his wife and children 2 years ago. The apartment consists of 2 bedrooms, kitchenette, 3 piece bathroom and living room.

In the master bedroom I used some of the existing circuit for the new lights and receptacles. Just recently 4 of 5 receptacles stopped working. I changed one of the receptacles that I thought was the fault. Everything worked fine and power was restored. I thought the old receptacle was the initial problem.

This morning my son informed me that the lights and clock were flickering off and on ( from the new receptacle I installed back ). The funny thing is, of the 5 receptacles in the line the last one is still working fine. Any ideas?

Comment: When you wired the receptacles, did you use pigtails to feed through, or did you use the receptacles themselves to feed through? Where there any changes made about the time the problem started? Are you sure all your connections are tight?  Flickering usually points to loose/bad connections.

Comment: It's really difficult to troubleshoot an electrical problem through the internet, so please add as much detail about the wiring as you can.

Comment: I used the receptacles to feed through. I used the screws on the side of each receptacle to tie in. I did not use the push ins on the back.

Comment: That is strange that the last one works I haven't seen that in the past. Are you sure of the direction of the feed? I would start at the  "last" one that is working. Verify the load side connections are good then check the next one that is not working line side or feed from the one that is working.  Looking for a loose connection or a broken wire.